# What version of ionic-native works with Ionic v1?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

In my Ionic v1 project, I upgraded from `ionic-native@2.2.16` to `ionic-native@2.9.0` and now I get an empty object error when I call `$cordovaFile.readAsText`. Also, `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition` never returns.

Does anyone know what version of `ionic-native` is compatible with Ionic v1?

The docs say that the `2.x` version should be compatible, but it's not (or there was a breaking change that I can't figure out).

Comment: ionic native is based on angular2 so I dont think it will work with v1 projects

Comment: Ionic Native is ment to be used for Ionic v2 projects, in case you'd like to use native plugins in your application (v1), you should use ngCordova

Comment: The readme for ionic-native states "For Ionic/Angular 1 support, please use version 2 of Ionic Native." - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native#ionic-1angular-1-support